# Как сравнить записи в двух таблицах SQLite?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

У меня 2 таблицы SQLite: **base** и **base_old**.

**base**:

```
id | number | change  
1  |  224  | 0    
2  |  278  | 0    
3  |  531  | 0    
4  |  124  | 0    
5  |  587  | 0    
7  |  968  | 0
```

**base_old**:

```
id | number | change  
1  |  119  | 15    
2  |  232  | 44    
3  |  523  | 53    
4  |  156  | 78    
6  |  377  | 5    
7  |  969  | 14
```

Мне нужно из таблицы **base_old** взять каждую строку и вычесть значения *number* из таблицы **base**, только если они имеют равные *id*. Результат записать в *change* таблицы **base**.

Например 1 строка: 224-119=105. 105 записываем в *change* таблицы **base**.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать с помощью SQL-запросов.

P.S. Пишу на python3

Comment: есть замечательный сайт https://metanit.com/sql/ там хорошо и доступно все объясняется:)

Comment: @TEA Спасибо, надеюсь, разберусь)

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, сработало) Напиши как ответ - отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE base b 
SET b.change = ( SELECT b.number-bo.number 
                 FROM base_old bo 
                 WHERE bo.id = b.id )
```